# Django не запускается manage.py

Tags: python, django

Подскажите пожалуйста, начал осваивать `Django`, но все встало в моменте, когда пытаюсь запустить сервер. В консоле пишу `py manage.py runserver` - ничего не происходит. Запускаю правильно, из папки расположения `manage.py. -migrate` так же не работает. Даже `-help`.

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны быть в директории своего проекта,тоесть открйте консоль впишите директорию проекта,откройте ту директорию,где у вас лежит manage.py(например cd D:/Проект) и там пропишите python manage.py runserver (именно так как я указал,если вы на маке то python 3manage.py runserver )

Comment: да, я именно оттуда и открываю

Comment: Ну вам надо не py manage.py runserver,а python manage.py runserver

Comment: Все равно не работает :( и python3 пробовал, и py и python...

Answer (score 0):

Для запуска сервера используйте команду `python manage.py runserver` или `./manage.py runserver`.

Если в системе несколько версий `python` то можете использовать `python3 ./manage.py runserver` или `virtualenv`.

Миграции: (`python manage.py makemigrations`, `python manage.py migrate`) или (`./manage.py makemigrations`, `./manage.py migrate`)

Заметьте, вы должны находиться в директории с файлом `manage.py` вашего проекта.

Comment: У меня ничего не происходит, нахожусь в папке проекта, консоль просто игнорирует обращение к файлу manage.py

Comment: @МайклАртурович Выполните `python manage.py runserver` пожалуйста и приведите скриншот терминала.

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/Yz_hxUHQ3gxa7g

Comment: @МайклАртурович а `python` точно установлен? Откуда вы его установили? Попробуйте команду: `python --version` и `python3 --version`
`

Comment: Да, точно установлен, но реагирует только на команду py https://yadi.sk/i/Q9Vgb84vDx5SJQ

Comment: @МайклАртурович Я так понял, что проблема ещё актуальна? Я погугли, похоже это из за того, что `windows` ищет пути `python` не там где нужно. Попробуйте удалить `питон` и заново скачать его из **Microsoft Store**, тогда вам не придется мучиться с путями.